# What are the 8 wires on this rechargeable lithium-ion battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am trying to replace a rechargeable lithium ion battery with one that has a longer lifespan when charged. The one I have has 8 wires, but every one I find has 2. It has 3 red, 3 black, 1 yellow, and 1 white.

[image: 3.7V 2200mAh rechargeable Lithium ion battery (8 wires)]

As you can see:
Rating: 3.7V 2200mAh

Can I replace it with something like this 6000mAh one, from SparkFun?
 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8484

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Open it and figure it out

Comment: That's why I'm asking you guys. I don't have a replacement one.

Comment: "The one I have has 8 wires" it seems you have the one you have to open, don't you?

Comment: The reds are positive, blacks are negative (it says so on the label). I'm guessing that the white and yellow ones are connected to a temperature sensor or other monitoring sensor.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What I don't get still is why there are 3 of each kind of terminal, instead of one. Can I convert them?

Comment: @Dampmaskin Yes indeed. Either straight 10 kohm NTC thermosensor or some I2C battery monitoring circuit. OP should pry it open very carefully outside using googles and find out what the sensor is. The product may or may not work without it. Please report your findings!

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you could confirm all that for me! Sure thing!

Comment: But what about those icons, where I believe it says, Be sure keep away from Oscar the grouch, Then run around in a circle 5 times, and Try to draw the Star of David. Electronics is interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the color code of the wires it's obvious that you have 3x `B-` and 3x `B+` on the sides. The schematic in the [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/6000mAh-3.7V-P-1S3804AD.pdf) suggests that the two wires in the middle are `P-` and `NTC`, for temperature sensing.

[image]

I don't speak any Chinese, so you can only trust my statement that much.

Regarding replacement batteries, if your system has only two wires, it's more or less safe to take a battery with extra connections (like temperature sensors) and simply ignore them. However, if your system expects a battery with temperature sensing, connecting a battery with only two wires is not recommended, and may be impossible: many systems won't charge a battery if they don't get a reasonable signal on the sensing inputs.

Comment: Thanks! So, any reason why it needs 3 wires each instead of 1 of each? Can I make it compatible?

Comment: You need 3 wires if you want to draw a lot of current. The bare minimum is 1 black and 1 red wire.

Comment: I'm sorry. How do I go about finding a battery like that? Or figuring out how to hook up more wires?

Comment: Does my last edit answer your question? Finding a battery like that is as easy as googling for "li-ion battery with NTC"

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right!

Comment: I'm laughing at how part of the circuit diagram has been flipped with the English backwards.